# Tfsec: how to write custom check for ec2 cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfsec

I used requiresPresence to check for the aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm but it randomly checks if the alarm resource is present but not for the corresponding ec2

this my custom check:

```
- code: MANAGED-CHECK-003
  description: Custom check to ensure EC2 CPU has CloudWatch la alarm
  impact: 
  resolution: TEST
  requiredTypes:
  - resource
  requiredLabels:
  - aws_instance
  severity: CRITICAL
  matchSpec:
    action: requiresPresence
    name: aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm
    subMatch:
      action: isPresent
      name: dimensions
      predicateMatchSpec:
        - name: InstanceId
          action: equals
          value: source
```

This is my resource

```
resource "aws_instance" "test_instance" {
  ami                    = "ami-test"
  instance_type          = "m5.xlarge"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.test_sg.id]
  key_name               = var.test_test
  iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_node_profile.name
  subnet_id              = var.test_subnet_id

}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm-test-cpu" {
  alarm_name                = "alarm-test-cpu"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "5"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "80"
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors test ec2 CPU utilization"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  alarm_actions             = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"

  dimensions = {
    InstanceId = aws_instance.test_instance.id
  }
}
```

The custom check also passes for

```
Instance.id = test_instance_1.id
```